# Регулярное выражение для .htaccess: любой .txt, кроме robots.txt

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

В корне сайта файл `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*.txt$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Здесь на любой запрос `txt` файла возвращается ошибка 404. Нужно изменить регулярное выражение:

```
^.*.txt$
```

Так, чтобы оно соответствовало всем файлам `.txt`, кроме `robots.txt`.

Comment: Я так понимаю вторая точка должна обозначать именно точку, а не любой символ. Значит, её стоит экранировать

Comment: пробовал вот так: ^(?!robots).txt$  и вот так ^(?!robots).*.txt$ - не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в заключается в том, что вы неправильно составили выражение. Попробуйте это:

```
^.*(?<!robots).txt$
```

Думаю не стоит объяснять простые детали, как: `^` - начало строки, `.*` - захват 0 и более символов; Затрону лишь `(?<!robots).txt` - эта конструкция говорит нам о том, что производится поиск слова перед которым нет `robots`, далее идет простой формат файла `.txt` и конец строки (`$`).

Answer (score 0):

Как временное решение, вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*.txt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Так как robots.txt у меня формируется динамически (php), то этот способ работает: все файлы с расширением .txt недоступны иp браузера, а вот динамический robots.txt - доступен.